# PDF is shown as binary text in browser instead of being downloaded

Tags: google-chrome, browser, pdf, url

In Chrome, when I enter a URL to a PDF file, usually the browser's Save dialog opens to save the PDF file to my hard disk, for example:

http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf

Now I have found a PDF URL where this, unfortunately, does not work:

https://formulare.bmf.gv.at/service/formulare/inter-Steuern/pdfd/2015/U1a.pdf

With this PDF URL, no Save dialog is opened and the binary text of this PDF is shown in the browser:

[image]

Why is this and how can I make it download automatically when I click the URL?

OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why is this and how can I download this PDF file?

The website is broken and is not serving PDF files correctly. Contact webmaster@bmf.gv.at.

Using the Firefox developer tools (press <kbd>f12</kbd>, select "Net", then select "All" we can see the response and request headers:

[image]

```
Content-Disposition inline;filename=U1a.pdf
```

The above [tells the browser to serve the page content inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition):

> In a regular HTTP response, the Content-Disposition response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally.

You can open the PDF by saving the page locally and opening the PDF:

1. Right click on the page and select "Save as" (or press <kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd></kbd>s)

   > [image]
2. Choose a directory and click "Save".
3. Navigate to the chosen directory in `Explorer`.
4. Double click `U1a.pdf`.

Comment: Thank you. How is the website not serving PDF files correctly? Can you please explain the technical details?

Comment: @user1580348 There are many different possibilities ...

Comment: For example? Can you name some, please?

Comment: @user1580348 The most likely is that the web server is serving the wrong mime type for pdf files and is serving it as html. See [Properly Configuring Server MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types)

Comment: IMO, this cannot be, as Firefox shows a correct MIME type for the PDF URL: `http://i.imgur.com/iPoybDn.png` (`application/pdf`).

Comment: @user1580348 It fails in Firefox in the same way for me. But works in IE. Strange.

Comment: Might be a attachment status header set to inline

Comment: @JohnKeates You got it `Content-Disposition inline;filename=U1a.pdf`

Comment: @user1580348 Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! So does this indicate that it's the server's fault or it's Chrome's fault?

Comment: Or more precisely: Is it the server's fault or is there an error in the website's HTML code containing the link to this PDF file?

Comment: @user1580348 `Content-Disposition inline;filename=U1a.pdf` is the response from the server, so it is the server that is misconfigured.

Comment: I needed to know whom I should blame: The server admin or the website developer. BTW, how could the server admin fix this? Thank you! (I am not maintaining the site; it's just for curiosity).

Comment: @user1580348 I would ask both of them. It depends where they have decided to split their responsibilities ...

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way out here which is mention in this [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en) is

> 1. On your computer, open Chrome.
> 2. Go to chrome://plugins.
> 3. Under "Chrome PDF Viewer," click Enable PDF viewing.

Comment: Did you actually try this? It doesn't work. The website is not serving PDF files correctly. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to view the PDF in the browser, I just want to download the PDF when I click on the URL.

Comment: Strange: When I enter the PDF URL `https://formulare.bmf.gv.at/service/formulare/inter-Steuern/pdfd/2015/U1a.pdf` in Firefox, the PDF is displayed correctly as PDF in Firefox (without downloading).

Comment: Ok sorry I missunderstood. and did not read your question thoroughly.

Comment: I have now activated `Chrome PDF Viewer` in `chrome://plugins`, but Chrome still displays the PDF as binary text. So why this (displaying the PDF in the browser) is working in Firefox and not in Chrome?

Comment: but to my surprise it did open in Mozilla and not in chrome very strange behavior I agree to your point.

Comment: this can be bug in either web server or chrome. More probable it is chrome bug as it opens in Mozilla

Comment: Also in Internet Explorer the PDF is displayed correctly as PDF (no download).

Comment: In Opera there is a strange security warning: It says that it is not possible to complete the secure transaction! ???